# longlistselector Context Menu NavigationService Wrong item

Tags: windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

i have a longlistselector and use contextmenu. I have problem when use NavigationService.

For each list item there is a context menu to delete or edit the item and that appears to work okay for pre-existing lists of items.
However, if I add a new person, add a new item to that person, edit it, then add another item, when I try to edit the second item, the first item is selected instead.

IS A BUG?

My Xaml code looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="LongListSelectorItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="4,4">
            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <toolkit:ContextMenu cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=LayoutRoot}">
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Edit" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Tap] = [Action ContextMenuEdit_EventTap($datacontext)]" />
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Delete" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Tap] = [Action ContextMenuDelete_EventTap($datacontext)]" />
                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name2}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the solution for your problem, but i had a same sort of problem and it works for me.

Add a name to the phoneApplicationPage (top of the xaml)

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
......
Your settings
......
x:Name="Page">
```

And change this code:

```
<toolkit:ContextMenu cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=LayoutRoot}">
```

Into this:

```
<toolkit:ContextMenu cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding ElementName=Page, Path=DataContext}">
```